# To the point of my knowledge

Tags: single-word-requests

Do you know any **words** to summarize "to the point of my knowledge"?

> To the point of my knowledge, in the literature review there are three publications about this idea.

I want it to be like this:

> In the literature review there are three publications about this idea _______.

How can I replace *To the point of my knowledge* by one word at the end of the sentence?

Comment: "As far as I know"?

Comment: [To the **best** of my knowledge](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22To+the+best+of+my+knowledge%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) OP is probably looking for that usage (as per about 12,400,000 written instances in Google Books there).

Comment: My question is : I am looking for a word summarize it?

Comment: Depending on the context, you could use: **as far as I'm aware** or **to the best of my knowledge**. You can also prefix or suffix with **I believe** or **I think**. A common internet initialism is AFAIK (as far as I know).

Comment: @dr.green *In the literature review there are, **to the best of my knowledge**, three publications about this idea*. You can, of course, shift the highlighted part to the end of the sentence, if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

I think “known” is the closest single word you can get, but it doesn’t fit your sentence and certainly can’t go at the end.

> The sentence is "to the point of our knowledge, in the literature review there are three publications about this idea and I wanted it to be like this: < In the literature review there are three publications about this idea (to the point of my knowledge)> How can I replace it by one word at the end of the sentence?

Here’s a short way of expressing your idea at the end of the sentence with a dangling preposition:

> In the literature review, there are three publications about this idea we know of.

One more letter (this sounds *much* less awkward):

> In the literature review, there are three publications about this idea known to us.

Not at the end:

> In the literature review, as far as we know, there are three publications about this idea.

Answer (score -3):

You can use *it seems to me* instead of *to the point of my knowledge*, then your sentence will like this:

> In the literature review there are three publications about this idea as it seems to me.

Answer (score -6):

You can say:

> In the literature review there are three publications about this idea have **foreseen**.

Comment: The way that sentence currently stands, it makes very little sense.

Comment: It isn't even grammatical, let alone meaningful. -1.

Comment: No, you really can’t.